# String Matching issue

Tags: python, pandas

Hi so I am trying to a condition where it prints certain attributes of a csv file. Here is the csv file:

```
hero_names  Agility
3-D Man TRUE
A-Bomb  FALSE
Abe Sapien  TRUE
Abin Sur    FALSE
Abomination FALSE
Abraxas FALSE
Absorbing Man   FALSE
Adam Monroe FALSE
Adam Strange    FALSE
```

I want to display all of the items in **hero_names** where the rows in **Agility** are "true"

How would I be able to do that? So far I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import string

super_hero_powers = pd.read_csv(r'super_hero_powers.csv', skiprows=0)

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
true="True"
DFagilityTrue=super_hero_powers[super_hero_powers['Agility'].str.match(true)]

#Return Rows were the conditions are both true
print(DFagilityTrue)
```

and the error i get is with "str.match", the error is " raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string values!")
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!"

Answer (score 0):

`super_hero_powers[super_hero_powers['Agility'].eq('TRUE')]`

Comment: Tried that, i get "FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  return op(a, b)"

Comment: Yes that's a warning based on your `pd.__version__`. But did you get an error or was the output incorrect? I'm on `pd.__version__ == 1.1.1`

Comment: since 'true' is a boolean, it wouldnt work as a string i believe?

Answer (score 0):

Being String values please use `.str.contains` while making  the `NaN` to be `False`

`super_hero_powers[super_hero_powers['Agility'].str.contains(r'TRUE', na=False, regex=True)]`

Comment: i'm on python 3.8